# Possessive for Mothers' Day

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives, apostrophe, saxon-genitive

OK, so we just passed Mothers' Day and I was curious as to why the card manufacturers all seem to think that the holiday is about one mother, i.e., mother's day vs. all mothers, mothers' day?

Comment: Maybe they think of each person dedicating the day to his own mother. Let's take Mother out for brunch; after all, this is Mother's day.

Comment: Not everyone writes it as _Mother's Day_ -- for some, it is (correctly) _**[Mothers' Day](http://www.newyorker.com/cartoons/a15695)**_

Comment: And I always thought it was 'Mothering Sunday'. There, that solves the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Mother's Day began in 1908 and was promoted by a women's organizer named Anna Jarvis.  It was founded in large part as a day for women to mourn those who had died in war and to work for peace.

See explanation of its naming below from [a National Geographic online article](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2014/05/140508-mothers-day-nation-gifts-facts-culture-moms/).

> "For Jarvis it was a day where you'd go home to spend time with your
>   mother and thank her for all that she did," West Virginia Wesleyan's
>   Antolini, who wrote "Memorializing Motherhood: Anna Jarvis and the
>   Defense of Her Mother's Day" as her Ph.D. dissertation, said in a
>   previous interview.
>
> **"It wasn't to celebrate all mothers. It was to celebrate the best
>   mother you've ever known—your mother—as a son or a daughter." That's
>   why Jarvis stressed the singular "Mother's Day," rather than the
>   plural "Mothers' Day**," Antolini explained.

Answer (score 1):

We can blame President Wilson. He wrote the proclamation. [https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/24/President_Woodrow_Wilson%27s_Mother%27s_Day_Proclamation_of_May_9%2C_1914_%28Presidential_Proclamation_1268%29._-*NARA*-_299965.jpg/768px-President_Woodrow_Wilson%27s_Mother%27s_Day_Proclamation_of_May_9%2C_1914_%28Presidential_Proclamation_1268%29._-*NARA*-_299965.jpg](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/24/President_Woodrow_Wilson%27s_Mother%27s_Day_Proclamation_of_May_9%2C_1914_%28Presidential_Proclamation_1268%29._-_NARA_-_299965.jpg/768px-President_Woodrow_Wilson%27s_Mother%27s_Day_Proclamation_of_May_9%2C_1914_%28Presidential_Proclamation_1268%29._-_NARA_-_299965.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the original intention of the creator and founder of Mother's/Mothers/Mothers'Day, the punctuation presently varies in use.

[I, personally, prefer the apostrophe after the "s", as I tend to celebrate all mothers and motherhood and nurturers of any gender on this day, whether or not they have birth- or adopted children, keeping in mind that some people have had more than one nurturer, eg, mother and step-mother, 2 adoptive mothers.]

> Source: http://www.betterwritingskills.com/tip-w011.html
>
> Example of use:
>   https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10212571484543508&set=a.1424886743602.2059916.1275766962&type=3&theater